# IN(CONCAT()) not returning results in MySQL for comma separated string

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Take the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
ON tableA.ID = tableB.pid
WHERE tableA.foo IN ('1234')
AND tableB.bar = 555
```

The query above returns 1 result.

Now, due to the nature of the data I have stored (comma separated string[ie: jkdjif,3-i-d,343), I attempt to replace the above IN() with this to wrap the data with quotes:

```
WHERE tableA.foo IN (CONCAT("'",REPLACE('1234',",","','"),"'"))
```

However, this returns 0 results.

It looks like something to do with the CONCAT() within the IN() as i've reduced it down to just `IN (CONCAT("'",643290,"'"))`

Why is this? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: probably you need to do array with values, not comma separated string

Comment: [`IN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) expects a list of values (or a result set). You pass it a string. Of course it doesn't work.

Comment: You are only passing a single argument to REPLACE() - 3 expected. What happens when you `SELECT (CONCAT("'",REPLACE('1234'),",","','"),"'"))` ?

Comment: @symcbean sorry, that was a typo in my SO question. corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.ID = tableB.pid
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tableA.foo, 'jkdjif,3-i-d,343') > 0
AND tableB.bar = 555
```